# Why does EST JavaScript Date sets 12:00:00AM to 0:00:00 AM?

Tags: javascript, date, clock, real-time-clock

my JavaScript display time function works fine, but once it hits 12:00:00 AM EST, it changes to 0:00:00 AM. **Essentially, I want it to show as 12:00:00 AM when the clock strikes midnight**. I have included my code below so anyone can help? Thank you!

```
let session = document.getElementById("session");

if (session) {
  displayTime();
  setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
  clearInterval(displayTime);
}

function displayTime() {
  let dateTime = new Date();
  let hrs = dateTime.getHours();
  let mins = dateTime.getMinutes();
  let sec = dateTime.getSeconds();

  if (hrs > 12) {
    session.innerHTML = "\xa0" + "PM";
  } else {
    session.innerHTML = "\xa0" + "AM";
  }

  if (hrs > 12) {
    hrs = hrs - 12;
  } 
  

  if (mins < 10) {
    mins = "0" + mins;
  }

  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }

  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hrs;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = mins;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = sec;
}
```

Comment: 00:00:00 is actually preferable over 12:00:00. There is ambiguity whether midnight and noon are AM or PM, and different conventions are or have been in use (which is why many style guides recommend avoiding AM/PM entirely for these times). 00:00:00, on the other hand, is unambiguously midnight.

Comment: Hi ! @Schnitte Yes, I understand what your saying, but for this particular project, I need it to read as 12:00:00. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to change.

- The condition to display "PM" should be `>= 12` instead of `> 12`
- The mapping of 24-hours to 12-hours should never leave 0 as-is. You can use the remainder operator.

Here are the corrected relevant lines:

```
  if (hrs >= 12) {
    session.innerHTML = "\xa0" + "PM";
  } else {
    session.innerHTML = "\xa0" + "AM";
  }

  hrs = (hrs + 11) % 12 + 1;
```

### Alternative

To format a time, look at [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) with its options:

```
dateTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US")
```

If you really need to chop the date parts into different elements on your HTML document, then:

```
function displayTime() {
  let dateTime = new Date();
  let [hrs, mins, sec, apm] = dateTime.toLocaleTimeString("en-US").split(/\W/);
  console.log(hrs, mins, sec, apm);
  document.getElementById("hours").textContent = hrs;
  document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = mins;
  document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = sec;
  document.getElementById("session").textContent = "\xa0" + apm;
}
```

### Remarks

Unrelated, but `clearInterval` is called at the wrong time and with the wrong argument, which luckily makes it ineffective, or your timer wouldn't tick at all.

`clearInterval` should get as argument a value that was returned by a previous call to `setInterval`.

In your code `clearInterval` is executed immediately after `setInterval`, which makes little sense. You should call it conditionally in the callback that is passed to `setInterval`. Maybe when a certain time has passed...

Comment: Hi @trincot, the two changes you provided worked. I'll look into your remarks later. Thank you again!